# Conflict Between Confidence Interval and P-values - One Sample T-Tests

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, mean, effect-size

I'm conducting one-sample t-test using R. I calculated p value, effect size, and confidence interval, but they seem to be conflicting. Here is a sample code and output:

```
data <- rnorm(98, mean = 0.1772012, sd = 0.01932061)
t.test(data, mu = 0.1718343)
```

Here is the first output:

```
    One Sample t-test

data:  data
t = 2.6291, df = 97, p-value = 0.009954
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.1718343
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1732420 0.1819127
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.1775773
```

Then I calculated effect size using the following command:

```
effsize::cohen.d(data, mu = 0.1718343, f = NA, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here is the second output:

```
Cohen's d (single sample)

d estimate: 0.2655839 (small)
Reference mu: 0.1718343
95 percent confidence interval:
     lower      upper 
-0.1371545  0.6683224
```

I have two questions:

1. There are two confidence intervals. The first one is [0.1732420, 0.1819127]. The second one is [-0.1371545, 0.6683224]. What are the differences between the two?
2. If I consider the second confidence interval (i.e., [-0.1371545, 0.6683224]) as the one to report, this CI crosses 0 which means it's null effect, but the p-value is significant. Isn't that conflicting?

Thanks.

Comment: The t interval is a 95% CI for the population mean $\mu.$ It is centered at the sample mean $\bar X = 
0.1775773.$ // Do you know what the CI in the output from the 'effect size' procedure is estimating?

Comment: According to the `effsize` package document (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effsize/effsize.pdf, page 6), the `cohen.d` function calculates the confidence interval based on non-central t distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer to my question.

The first CI coming out of `t.test` means the confidence interval of the mean.

The second CI coming out of `cohen.d` means the confidence interval of the effect size.

Therefore, although the test is significant (according to p-value), the effect size is small with a 95% CI that covers 0.